Cannot load two temporary extensions at the same time in Firefox?
I load a temporary  extension(with a content script) in Firefox by "about:debugging#/runtime/this-firefox" and this extension works fine. Then I load another temporary  extension(with a background script) using the same method and this works fine too. But soon the two extensions stop working even after restarting Firefox/removing/reloading the extensions. Now, I cannot load any  temporary  extension and let it work. I think loading two extensions at the same time may cause some problem with Firefox permanently. How can I reset Firefox's state for running extensions?

Works for me, so probably a bug in Firefox. Try creating a new user profile in Firefox.

@wOxxOm Creating a new profile solves the problem. Thanks. But I lose my settings and bookmarks in the new profile. I'd like a solution to work in the old profile.
